# How to refresh a BeanFieldGroup after a client request whitout a button?

Tags: ajax, refresh, components, httprequest, vaadin

i hope i will find help here.
Is it possible to refresh a single component in Vaadin.

For example do a client request which change a value [ *type = String*] inside a single component and refresh this component after it immediate.

Here the content for better understanding:

My Vars:
`private static BeanFieldGroup<Service> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<Service>(Service.class);`
`private FormLayout form = new FormLayout();`

My Constructor:

```
public ServiceDetails()
{
    vl = new CssLayout();
    vl.addComponent(new Label("Service Details"));
    vl.addComponent(form);
    vl.setStyleName("details");
    vl.setSizeFull();

    addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPropertyChangeListener());

    refreshBT = new Button("Show Updated Content");
    form.addComponent(refreshBT);
    addListener();



    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("S-ID: ", "id"));
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Name: ", "name"));
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Description: ", "description"));
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Service Tags: ","allTagsOfService")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Attributes: ","allInOnAtt")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Capabilities: ","allInOnCapa")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Categorization: ","allInOnCat")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Relations: ","allInOnRela")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Stakeholder: ","allInOnStkh")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Resources: ","allInOnRes")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Quality: ","quality")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Process: ","process")); 
    form.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Finance: ","finance"));  
    form.setImmediate(true);

    setCompositionRoot(vl);

}
```

The Button will update the shown content for the user. If a AJAX-request is done the data will be at the server but not shown. If the button is clicked the userview will be updated correctly.

Each variable change call a method which setup my content for the BeanFieldGroup.

```
public void setService(Service service)
{
    setServ(service);
    binder.setItemDataSource(getServ());
}
```

The Problem is now that i need to click this button for a userview refresh, if i clicked on the service inside a canvas structure. By the way this structure is realized in javascript, and a click will always do a AJAX-request [ *type =  POST*] to the server. The send data will be saved correctly in a temporary variable but nothing will be shown at my page. The content change will not be shown to the user page. But this only appear if i use AJAX-requests. If i do click at another component it works without using the button.  `):`

Any idea how to fix this kind of problem.
Thx for each reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with http, you have to keep in mind, that the server usually can't inform the client about changes done on server side.

In vaadin, if you modify the UI on server side, outside of the normal "Action from client", then these changes will show up only on the next interaction with the client.

If you need to send the changes from the server to the client, you will have to use a push technology, where the server can inform the client about new/changed content.

Fortunally vaadin includes a easy to use implementation of this push system.

In the `Book of Vaadin` there is a [complete section about server push](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html).

Basically you add the `@Push` annotation to your UI class and add the required libraries.

You have to keep in mind, that you will need to synchronize access to the UI to get consistent results. (Also documented in the `book of vaadin`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply André i will try it this way you describe.

Comment: Thanks alot André it does exactly what i want.